# Accessing class variables

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

It's the first time I use OOP with PHP 5.. so this is my problem..

I have a file `disp.php` that contains a class named class disp (model in MVC)

```
<?php
class disp{
public $n_pages;
public $current_page;
private $cmd2;

/***************SQL command generator*******************/
private function getCmd2($cmd1,$id,$first_entry,$perpage,$tri){
    $cmd2=str_replace('COUNT(*)','*',$cmd1);
    $cmd2=$cmd2.' ORDER BY '.$id.' '.$tri.' LIMIT '.$first_entry.','.$perpage;
    return $cmd2;
}


/********************Items display******************/
function dispItems($cmd1,$id,$perpage,$tri){
  require('global/connection.inc.php');
  try{

     foreach($pdo->query($cmd1)as $r){
       $n_pages=ceil($r[0]/$perpage);
           if (isset ($_GET['pg'])){
          $current_page=intval($_GET['pg']);
               if ($current_page>$n_pages){
                    $current_page=$n_pages;
               }
               if ($current_page<=0){
                   $current_page=1;
               }
           }
           else{
           $current_page=1;
           $_GET['pg']=1;
           }
    }


    $i=1;
    $first_entry=($current_page-1)*$perpage;

    $objet=new disp();
     $cmd2=$objet->getCmd2($cmd1,$id,$first_entry,$perpage,$tri);

    $data=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($pdo->query($cmd2) as $r){
    $data[$i]=$r;
    $i++;
    }

  return $data;
  }catch(PDOException $e){}
}
}
```

this is the file `news.php` (controller in MVC):

```
require MODELS_DIR.'disp.php';
$objet=new disp();
$news=$objet->dispItems('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_nouveautes','ID_EVENT',10,'DESC');

$c_page=$objet->$current_page;
$n_pages= $objet->$n_pages;


require VIEWS_DIR.'disp-news.php';
```

in this code, I created an object (objet) of the type disp... I want to use the variables declared in the function `dispItems`, (`$n_pages` and `$current_page`) in the view (`disp-news.php`)

so I think that the class variables are the same variables in the function `dispItems()`... but when trying to access them from the controller ...using object. it shows me a error :

See:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: n_pages in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\example\admin\global\news.php on line 14

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.1\www\example\admin\global\news.php on line 14
```

Inspite of `$n_pages` and `$current_pages` being public in the class disp

thank you in advance

Comment: Now that I look back 8 years ago, That code is really a mess lol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
c_page=$objet->$current_page;
n_pages= $objet->$n_pages;
```

should be

```
$c_page=$objet->current_page;
$n_pages= $objet->n_pages;
```

Comment: it was just a mistake when copying the code ... thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry Dogbert, I did not observed the second $ after -> , I thought you are speaking only abut the first $ in every line  +1

Answer (score 6):

In the body of non-static class methods you need to access class members like `$this->current_page`, not `$current_page`

Comment: That's applied to all your members (`$cmd2`, `$npages`, etc), not just `$current_page`

Comment: still the same error ... I changed all the variables as you suggested but in vain

Comment: It looks like you have `n_pages` instead of `$n_pages` somewhere in your code.  Also, as Dogbert said, you should write `$n_pages= $objet->n_pages;`, not `$n_pages= $objet->$n_pages;` as in your edited code(just one `$`!!!)

Comment: Aah , okey, I did not observed that you did not write the second $ , I will try :-) thank you so much +1