# PHP - access class variable

Tags: php, class

how do i access a class variable in php ?

```
class Human 
{
    public $data = array(5,0,15,20,22,14,13,15,12,22,40,4); 

    public function test()
    {
      var_dump(json_encode($this->$data));
    }

}
```

Error :

**(1/1) FatalThrowableError**

Cannot access empty property

Comment: it's a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139508/accessing-class-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$`:

```
var_dump(json_encode($this->data));
```